# Do you need to load contents of Entity Framework collection before you .Add() to it?

Tags: entity-framework, collections, orm

I have an entity model with

```
class Package
{
...

    virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}
```

and am implementing an `AddOwner()` operation.

Does the entity framework require me to retrieve my Package object *including owners* with `.Include(p => p.Owners)` in order for me to call `p.Add(newOwner)`; and save changes back to the database?

**Secondary question** : Intuition isn't guiding me to an answer here because I don't know whether to base my intuition on CLR collections or on some principle of Entity Framework; is there a principle of EF that helps me understand things better than thinking in terms of CLR collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your `Package` object is attached to a context, the `Owners` property will be set to an `EntityCollection<Owner>`. Regardless of whether it's loaded, changes through that property will be marked as changes in your context, and `SaveChanges()` will save those changes.

Keep in mind that your `Owner` object already needs to be part of the context, if it is an existing owner, though. If it is not, EF will assume you are trying to save a new `Owner`.

Comment: so bottom line is there was no need to call .Include(p => p.Owners ) right?

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith As long as you have no other code that relies on `Owners` being loaded, right, that's not necessary. The only change from EF's side is that key violations (duplicate `Owner`s) will not be detected until `SaveChanges()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Owners will have to point to something concrete sooner or later, and certainly before you try adding anything to it. EF knows to look at this property through the ICollection interface.

You could do something such as:

```
var p = new Package { SomePackageProperty = "Some value",
Owners = new List<Owner>>() { new Owner { SomeOwnerProperty = "Some other value" } } };

yourContext.DbSet<Package>().Add(p);
```

But that's just a best guess, given the small snippet provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking of including Owners .Include(p => p.Owners), and then saying p.Owners.Add(new_owner) to add a new Owner, which will work after .SaveChanges.